# Insert value list does not match column list expecting 36 but got 30

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to load a JSON file from Azure ADLS gen2 to snowflake using Talend and I'm getting the below error:

net.snowflake.client.loader.ProcessQueue run
SEVERE: State: INGEST_DATA, INSERT INTO "Y_ACCXXXTAIL"(
"XXX",
"XX",
"XXXXX",
I HAVE 36 COLUMNS LIKE THIS
)
SELECT * FROM "Y_ACCXXXTAIL_20210226_132647_278_1", SQL compilation error:

Insert value list does not match column list expecting 36 but got 30

Please help, if you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error and the information you provided, I'd suggest you check the structure of your input JSON-file. It looks like there are just 30 and not 36 columns behind your "*"-syntax.

Comment: you are correct source file contains 30 columns only but for the rest of the columns I'm not loading any data, but that should not be blocking the insert.  Because for the remaining 6 columns I don't have any data. and I'm loading this table with talent not through insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the # of columns in your source file.
2. Check the # of columns in your target table. Here's a query for that one:

```
Select count(column_name) 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where table_name='TABLE NAME';
```

3. Make sure the column count matches when you run your INSERT

Finally, you should probably avoid using SELECT * in your INSERT statement for the future. Specifying column names is generally more performant than a  SELECT * and you will be able see that the column order makes sense. Otherwise, you may get a future error about mismatched data types if the table structure changes.

Comment: I'm loading data using Talend, not through SQL script. Yes, I have only 30 columns from source mapped to target, the rest 6 columns should be null

Comment: Does Talend give you the option to list out the column names from your source rather than doing a SELECT *? Matching the columns between your source and target should solve your problem. You could also just remove the 6 columns in your INSERT / table definition that should be null.

Comment: I'm not  doing select * or insert into, I'm mapping all fields in tmap component from source to target